# Plotly layer control: how to add texts in in front of shapes

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using plotly to display some shapes and add some annotations (text) over them. However I don't know how to control layer ordering to plot objects in plotly and the text is always behind the shapes (I didn't found any example in plotly R API docs).

Here follows a reproducible example:

```
library("plotly")

shapes <- list(
  list(type = "rect",
       fillcolor = "red", line = list(color = "white"),
       x0 = 0.0, x1 = 0.5, xref = "x",
       y0 = 0.0, y1 = 1.0, yref = "y",
       opacity = 0.3),
  list(type = "rect",
       fillcolor = "grey", line = list(color = "white"),
       x0 = 0.5, x1 = 1.0, xref = "x",
       y0 = 0.0, y1 = 1.0, yref = "y",
       opacity = 0.98)
)

plot_ly() %>%
  layout(shapes = shapes) %>%
  add_text(x = c(0.25, 0.75), y = 0.5, text = c("Easy Visible", "Barely visible"), textfont = list(color = '#000000'))
```

Which produces the following output (using opacity parameter we can see that the text is behind the shape):

[image]

Any idea on how to add texts in front of opaque shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `layer="below"` option to `shapes`. It specifies whether shapes are drawn below or above traces.

```
shapes <- list(
  list(type = "rect",
       fillcolor = "red", line = list(color = "white"),
       x0 = 0.0, x1 = 0.5, xref = "x",
       y0 = 0.0, y1 = 1.0, yref = "y",
       opacity = 0.3, layer="below"),
  list(type = "rect",
       fillcolor = "grey", line = list(color = "white"),
       x0 = 0.5, x1 = 1.0, xref = "x",
       y0 = 0.0, y1 = 1.0, yref = "y",
       opacity = 0.98, layer="below")
)

plot_ly() %>%
  layout(shapes = shapes) %>%
  add_text(x = c(0.25, 0.75), y = 0.5, 
           text = c("Easy Visible", "Barely visible"), 
           textfont = list(color = '#000000'))
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why the grid lines come back using this method?

Comment: @astrofunkswag With `layer="below"` the colored areas are placed behind any other object (grid lines, text, etc.). Your solution is very interesting. I like it !

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use annotations instead of text:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  layout(shapes = shapes) %>% 
  add_annotations( x = c(0.25, 0.75), 
                   y = c(0.5, .5),
                   xref = "x",
                   yref = "y",
                   text = c('Easy Visible', 'Also Easy Now'),
                   font = list(color = '#000000'), showarrow = F)
```

[image]